# How to disable all dates prior to a specific day in the DatePicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am new to using `Bootstrap datepicker`. I have two `datepickers` in my page: `FromDate` and `ToDate`. I want the all the dates that are prior to a specific date called `lastDate` to be disabled in the `FromDate` datepicker only. I have the following code:

**Razor**

```
<input type='text' asp-for="FromDate" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Click here..." id="fromDate" name="fromDate" required checkdate data-date-form>
```

**jQuery**

```
var lastDate = @ViewBag.LastDate;

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: lastDate

});
```

Upon implementing this, I am still able to select dates prior to the `lastDate`. I understand that `.datepicker` is referring to the `datepicker` class. However, I am not sure if I can use `#fromDate` ID in place of `.datepicker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard date [format](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) is: “mm/dd/yyyy”

If your **lastDate** does not respect that format you need to specify your specific format:

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
   startDate: '18/08/2018'
});
```

```js
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '18/08/2018'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <input type='text' asp-for="FromDate" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Click here..."
           id="fromDate" name="fromDate" required checkdate data-date-form>
```